# how to create and use a self-defined shared library with gcc?

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, makefile

I'm trying to write a simple example shared library makefile, but I met some bugs and cannot handle it, please help me, thanks.

This is my makefile:

```
exampleMain.o: exampleMain.cpp
g++ -std=c++11 -I./ -Wall -g -c exampleMain.cpp


# (1) Basic

example.o: example.cpp
    g++ -std=c++11 -I./ -Wall -g -c example.cpp

basic: example.o exampleMain.o
    g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -g -pthread example.o exampleMain.o -o basic.exe


# (2) Static Library

static.o: example.cpp
    g++ -std=c++11 -I./ -Wall -g -c example.cpp -o static.o

libstatic.a: static.o
    ar rcs libstatic.a static.o

static: libstatic.a exampleMain.o
    g++ exampleMain.o libstatic.a -pthread -o static.exe


# (3) Simple Shared Library

shared.o: example.cpp
    g++ -std=c++11 -I./ -Wall -g -fPIC -c example.cpp -o shared.o

libshared.so: shared.o
    g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,libshared.so -o libshared.so shared.o

shared: libshared.so exampleMain.o
    g++ exampleMain.o -o shared.exe -L./ -lshared -pthread


# (4) Clean

clean:
    rm *.o *.so *.a *.exe *.so.*
```

This makefile support 4 operation:

- (1) make basic: basic.exe
- (2) make static: static.exe
- (3) make shared: shared.exe
- (4) make clean: rm objects

(3) can be make, but when I try "./shared.exe", it says: ./shared.exe: error while loading shared libraries: libshared.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Here's my example code and makefile link: https://github.com/zhaochenyou/Tips/tree/master/tool_chain/make/basic

Comment: The problem is not your makefile. You need to tell the dynamic linker how to find the library at run time, using either RPATH or LD_LIBRARY_PATH. This has been asked and answered thousands of times on stackoverflow and elsewhere. Search for "error while loading shared libraries"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make has built in rules for much of what you need, the following should work with the caveat that you'll need to remake the `.o` files when switching between shared and non-shared

```
CXXFLAGS := -std=c++11 -Wall -g -pthread
LDFLAGS  := -g -pthread

basic.exe static.exe shared.exe: exampleMain.o
basic.exe:  example.o
static.exe: libstatic.a
shared.exe: libshared.so

libstatic.a: libstatic.a(example.o)

libshared.so: CXXFLAGS += -fPIC
libshared.so: LDFLAGS += -shared -Wl,-soname,libshared.so
libshared.so: example.o

basic.exe static.exe shared.exe libshared.so:
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

clean: ; $(RM) exmapleMain.o example.o libshared.so libstatic.a basic.exe static.exe shared.exe
```

Important note: **never** use wildcards when deleting, you might delete something you aren't responsible for.

As for the error read [this](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html), particularly the "Installing and Using a Shared Library" section.

Comment: Thanks for your patience, I can see your makefile is much better than mine, thanks a lot for your sharing.

Comment: @zhaochenyou I only realized your question wasn't actually related to the makefile after reading Jonathan's comment, still I'm glad you find the answer useful.

Comment: Yes, it's actually useful, my makefile is too much raw, yours is professional.

Answer (score 0):

With help of @user657267, I write an example makefile, it supports these:

- make basic.exe
- make libstatic.a
- make static.exe
- make libshared.so
- make shared.exe

The source cpp file is example.hpp, example.cpp, exampleMain.cpp. There're a simple example function, and a main function.
Here's the mainfile:

```
# additional compile flags
# CFLAGS for c
# CXXFLAGS for c++
CXXFLAGS := -std=c++11 -Wall -g -pthread -I./

# additional link flags
LDFLAGS  := -pthread

# dependent object
basic.exe static.exe shared.exe: exampleMain.o
basic.exe:  example.o
static.exe: libstatic.a
shared.exe: libshared.so

# additional link flags for shared.exe
# NOTICE: -Wl,-rpath=./ is for libshared.so runtime path
shared.exe: LDFLAGS += -L./ -Wl,-rpath=./

# NOTICE: this command also works:
# libstatic.a: libstatic.a(example.o)
libstatic.a: example.o
    ar rcs libstatic.a example.o

# additional compile and link flags for libshared.so
libshared.so: CXXFLAGS += -fPIC
libshared.so: LDFLAGS += -shared -Wl,-soname,libshared.so
# dependent object
libshared.so: example.o

# $^: all dependent objects
# $@: all target objects
# $(CXX): default c++ compiler
# $(LDLIBS): default c++ libraries
basic.exe static.exe shared.exe libshared.so:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

# $(RM): default rm command
clean:
    $(RM) exmapleMain.o example.o libshared.so libstatic.a basic.exe static.exe shared.exe
```